# How to check if the display is currently on full screen?

Tags: linux, i3

I have some notifications I want to send *only* when an application is full screen. For example if I have a video on full screen, and I increase or decrease the volume, I want to be notified what the new value is. If I'm not full screen, I don't want the notification since my bar already tells me.

Is there a command to get the fullscreen status? I'm also thinking checking if polybar is visible would work, but I have not found a way to do that either.

I am using i3 with polybar.

Comment: duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/30147/command-to-determine-whether-a-fullscreen-application-is-running

Answer (score 0):

Went with the second solution (checking if polybar is visible). The command xwininfo gives information on visibility. I used xdotool to get the id and grep to check for the value; leading to the final line:

`xwininfo -id $(xdotool search -name polybar) | grep IsViewable`

If this value is empty, polybar is not visible and you are probably in full screen.

Not going to accept this though, since it doesn't answer the original question of "How to check if the display is currently on full screen?".